# Is it possible to hide the mouse cursor when using a mouse and Remote Desktop on an android OS?

Tags: remote-access, mouse

I am running an Acer A3-A20 with Android OS version 4.4.2.

I have an adapter for a mouse that I wish to use when I am working remotely (I use the Remote Desktop app to accomplish remoting into my home system (Windows 10 upgraded from Windows 7 Ultimate)).

One thing is a little disconcerting - When I run in Mouse Pointer mode on RDP, the Android mouse cursor is laid over the cursor of the system I am remoted into.

The issue is... not resolved by turning the RDP mode from cursor to point because, while the system mouse cursor disappears, the Android OS cursor is still present (fine) but slightly inaccurate (not okay).

Is it possible to (either through the Android OS or through the RDP app) turn off the hardware cursor and leave just the standard white cursor?